# How to get the dynamically created form values in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed a form in dynamically using some edit text,check boxes,radio buttons and buttons.I have created form successfully ,but how i can get the values from that and stored in database.Please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

```
public void textView() {
        idText++;
        i++;

        LinearLayout linearLayoutHorizantal1 = new LinearLayout(
                getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutHorizantal1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        /*
         * LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new
         * LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams
         * .WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         * linearLayoutHorizantal1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         */
        txtQuetion = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        txtQuetion.setText(i + ". " + strQuestionText);
        txtQuetion.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txtQuetion.setTextSize(20);
        txtQuetion.setId(idText);
        linearLayoutHorizantal1.addView(txtQuetion);
        linearLayoutDynamicAdd.addView(linearLayoutHorizantal1);
    }

    public void RadioButtons() {

        radiogroup = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
        radiogroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                SurveyFillActivity.this, null);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);
        linearLayoutDynamicAdd.addView(radiogroup);
        for (int j = 0; j < answersList.length; j++) {
            if (answersList[j] != null) {
                idRadio++;
                rb = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
                rb.setId(idRadio);
                rb.setText(answersList[j]);
                rb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                rb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_custom);
                // rb.setChecked(true);
                rb.setLayoutParams(params);
                radiogroup.addView(rb);
            }
        }
    }

    private EditText editText(int _intID) {

        idEditBox++;
        final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(350, 50);
        final EditText et = new EditText(this);
        lparams.leftMargin = 20;
        lparams.topMargin = 10;
        et.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        et.setWidth(32);
        et.setEms(50);
        et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customborder_backbutton);
        /*
         * EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
         * et.setId(idEditBox); et.setHeight(60); et.setWidth(50);
         */
        //et.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        String s1 = et.getText().toString();
        linearLayoutDynamicAdd.addView(et, lparams);
        return et;
    }
```

The above code for creating forms and i need to get the values form it and store in Database.

Comment: show your form code..

Comment: what you have tried??..and what is the problem??

Comment: Store the edittexts and radiobuttons as field variables, then u can access them and their content from a storeToDatabase method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the arrays for texviews and radiobuttons ...what ever you need in your form.

take this as reference

```
         TextView tv[] = new TextView[HowManyYouNeed];
           TextView tvsa = new TextView(YourContax);
    tv[position]=tvsa;//position like o ..1..2
    tv[0].getText();
```

May be help full..